# How to install Xlib on Windows (eclipse , c language)

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, cmd, xlib

Ok, I need to use this for graphical programming, GUI, for cs 349 uwaterloo first assignment. I see random Xlib.h and Xutil.h files lying around on google search results. But no where does it say how I install or download Xlib from some website of something. I even tried to copy paste the Xlib.h onto a new files I created in my blank project and it has more than 100 errors. So... what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpliest way is to install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) - you'll get gcc + other tools (binutils, make, autotools) and X server and client libraries.

If C/C++ language is not a requirement I suggest to look at [python](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/) or [javascript](https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11) clients - both are easy to install and don't require X runtime at all (they implement X11 wire protocol themselves).