# How does Tkinter work on Microsoft Windows?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I was reading the up on Tkinter for certain [operations](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#wm.Wm.aspect-method) that the windows manager handles and I got to wondering how exactly does Tkinter communicate with the OS's window manager? Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#how-tk-and-tkinter-are-related) it uses Xlib to draw graphics, but how does that work on Microsoft Windows? Isn't Xlib a Unix-like grahpics library, i.e. X11? How exactly does Tkinter communicate with Windows graphics? Does the Windows version of Python have access to the WinAPI and doesnt use Xlib?

Comment: Here is something to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598416/how-to-install-xlib-on-windows-eclipse-c-language

Comment: @alexis that is actually unrelated to the question at hand; the Python docs say Tkinter uses Xlib to draw graphics for X Windows, but Microsoft Windows does not use the X Windows System; so how does Tkinter draw graphics on the Windows OS?

Comment: The link makes it clear that the assumption behind the question, "X11 is not available on Windows", is false. But I'm not surprised that Tkinter uses an appropriate graphics platform for each OS. (And you're right, it does not relate to the question of how tkinter _actually_ does it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tk (the library upon which tkinter is base) uses the windows API on windows, and cocoa libraries on OSX. Those two platforms don't use xlib, though it is possible to compile X11-based versions on those platforms if you wish.

A lot of information about the windows port of tcl/tk is available on the Tcl wiki: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Microsoft+Windows+and+Tcl

Comment: Great thanks! Side question, how on earth do you navigate that Wiki?? From "Home" I could not figure out how to get to the page you linked.